# reading library method definitions

Tags: python

If I want to see what a method does such as the method gauss in the module random, how would I do so using the Python Interpreter? For example after I type import random into the console of the Python interpreter what could I do to find out the actual code of the method gauss in module random without having to look at the actual file. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
import inspect
inspect.getsource(random.gauss)
```

Comment: why not just: `inspect.getsource(random.gauss)`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [IPython](http://ipython.org/), you could do this:

```
>>> random.gauss??
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not available from the default python shell, this is one of the many features of [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html).

```
In [4]: %psource random.gauss
    def gauss(self, mu, sigma):
        """Gaussian distribution.

        mu is the mean, and sigma is the standard deviation.  This is
        slightly faster than the normalvariate() function.

        Not thread-safe without a lock around calls.

        """

        # When x and y are two variables from [0, 1), uniformly
        # distributed, then
        #
        #    cos(2*pi*x)*sqrt(-2*log(1-y))
        #    sin(2*pi*x)*sqrt(-2*log(1-y))
        #
        # are two *independent* variables with normal distribution
        # (mu = 0, sigma = 1).
        # (Lambert Meertens)
        # (corrected version; bug discovered by Mike Miller, fixed by LM)

        # Multithreading note: When two threads call this function
        # simultaneously, it is possible that they will receive the
        # same return value.  The window is very small though.  To
        # avoid this, you have to use a lock around all calls.  (I
        # didn't want to slow this down in the serial case by using a
        # lock here.)

        random = self.random
        z = self.gauss_next
        self.gauss_next = None
        if z is None:
            x2pi = random() * TWOPI
            g2rad = _sqrt(-2.0 * _log(1.0 - random()))
            z = _cos(x2pi) * g2rad
            self.gauss_next = _sin(x2pi) * g2rad

        return mu + z*sigma
```

This is the same as typing `random.gauss??` as suggested by @icktoofay